# Why does tmux fail to "scroll" when entering a command that exceeds one line? (OSX Terminal.app)

Tags: command-line, tmux, line-editor

When I use `tmux` and enter a command that exceeds the line, it fails to redraw the previous line. It simply clears the current line and I can't see what I just wrote. **It does only redraw the first line.**

This also happens when I press <kbd>up</kbd> and the last command does not fit the current line (I only see the last line).   If I then press <kbd>up</kbd> and <kbd>down</kbd> again, I can see all lines of the command.

I'm not sure what causes that problem, but it's pretty annoying. Does it have to do something with my prompt? Just in case, here it is:

```
export PS1="%{$fg[blue]%}%n%{$reset_color%}@%{$fg[green]%}%m %{$fg[yellow]%}%~ %{$reset_color%}% "
export PS2=$_>
($TERM is set to screen)
```

By the way, I'm using zsh and OSX Termial, but the problem is also there with bash.

Also the problem does not exist with `xterm` (XQuartz), so i guess it's caused by OSX' Terminal.app.

- Does anyone know a way to fix this anyways?
- Perhaps I could force a redraw somehow?

Just found [this old thread](http://sourceforge.net/p/tmux/mailman/message/25779958/) on the tmux mailinglist.

I tried different values for `$TERM` (screen, screen-256colors, xterm, xterm-color, nsterm) but the error persists.

So I guess there is nothing I can do despite switching to another terminal emulator?

Comment: I have the same problem with tmux and would appreciate a solution. It's not a problem with the prompt, as one can verify by setting the prompt to something trivial.

Answer (score 3):

This is a bug in Terminal.app which has been noticed by others, e.g., in *[Any way to fix screen's mishandling of line wrap? (Maybe only Terminal.app)](https://superuser.com/questions/46948/any-way-to-fix-screens-mishandling-of-line-wrap-maybe-only-terminal-app)*

I can reproduce the effect using bash+tmux, and capturing the text sent to the screen see that tmux is setting the scrolling margins to exclude the last line on the screen before updates that might cause a wrapped line.  Meanwhile, bash is writing a long line by writing the part which would fit on the first line, *plus* two more characters, and then a carriage return and the second line, etc.

The two extra characters should force the line to wrap.  But Terminal.app appears to be confused by the switch of scrolling margins along with moving the cursor to the last line of the scrolling region and then writing a long line there.  Instead of wrapping, it stays where it is, and the second part of the long line is written on top of the first.

While there *is* a feature to turn off line-wrapping, most applications assume that it is enabled.  In the trace (using `script`), neither tmux nor bash used it.  Unless one of those manipulates the line-wrapping, there's nothing to gain there.  tmux, for instance, just *assumes* the feature and does not even check the terminal description for the `am` (automargin) capability.  It does check the related `xenl` flag (newline glitch), but removing that from the terminal description would only make things worse.

So... if this bug stops you from using Terminal.app, iTerm2 is a suitable alternative.

Comment: Thanks, this has bugged me very much lately, I will give iTerm2 a try. Besides, Terminal.app has been crashing on me lately as well. It has never been a better time to try iTerm2. (OS 10.12.3 Sierra here)

Answer (score 0):

I would just download iterm2 and use that.
Most fellow developers I know that use mac just do that.

I think you will find it a more pleasurable environment.

I use iterm2 with tmux and it works great.

http://www.iterm2.com

Comment: tmux is a terminal server similar to 'screen' used to maintain multiple terminal sessions on a remote system. iterm2 is great, but irrelevant to this issue.