# Why is my output not wrapping in tmux?

Tags: terminal, osx, zsh, tmux

I am currently running tmux within Terminal.app on my Mac.

When I execute a command that outputs a line longer than the available window, instead of wrapping onto the next line, it overwrites the existing line.

What is also strange about this is: if I CMD+TAB to a different application and CMD+TAB back the output appears correctly on multiple lines.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: make sure you are not overriding `TERM=screen` inside tmux.

Comment: Can you reproduce this without any of your configuration files (`.tmux.conf`, `.zshrc`, etc.)? (It may help to test on another account that isn't customized in any way.) If not, post a complete set of configuration files that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I answered this last May in

[Why does tmux fail to “scroll” when entering a command that exceeds one line? (OSX Terminal.app)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/140605/why-does-tmux-fail-to-scroll-when-entering-a-command-that-exceeds-one-line-o)

It is a known bug which does not appear with iTerm2.